# Adding constraints to integers

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I am trying to limit the input number to be greater than 0 and an integer.

Code Here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PROB4_CHAL1   // Sum of Numbers
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

 int sum = 0;
 int count = 1;
 int number = 1;

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Enter an integer " + 
              "greater than 0.");
 number = input.nextInt();

 while (number >= count) 
 {
  sum += count;
  count ++;
 }

 System.out.println("Sum equals " + sum);


}
}
```

New to Java so anything will help!

Comment: check if number is valid after calling nextInt() and ask again if it is not.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user types a negative integer?  Should the program go back and ask them to re-enter it?  If so, you'll need some kind of a loop, such as a do-while.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @mikeyaworski, please be more careful when selecting tags.  You created a new tag instead of using an existing, correct tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: @Charles Will do. Usually I use `java-util-scanner` anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the input in a while loop, like so:

```
int number = 0; // start at 0 so the while loop is true for the first time

while (number < 1) {

    System.out.println("Enter an integer " + 
                       "greater than 0.");
    number = input.nextInt();
}
```

This way it will keep asking them to input a number until the number they input is greater than 0.

Comment: I am trying to add 1,2,3,4,5... to the input number. That code will bring a sum of 0

Comment: @nerd4life: My code has nothing to do with your method of gathering the sum. Don't replace your current while loop, just replace your `number = input.nextInt();` with my loop.